# Warnings when installing R package with Rcpp

Tags: rcpp

I am tring to build an R package with Rcpp using Rstudio. When I click "install and restart", Rstudio outputs hundreds of warning information and I cannot easily find the error information. I tried to find out reason to avoid the warning information but failed. It seems the warnings are from Rcpp package. BTW, the package can still work.

The below is the additional options for `R CMD INSTALL`

```
--no-multiarch --with-keep.source
```

The information can be replicated using the below commands

```
library(devtools)  # author version: 2.3.0, use install.packages("devtools") first
install_github("GeneticAnalysisinBiobanks/GRAB", INSTALL_opts=c("--no-multiarch"))  # The INSTALL_opts is required in Windows OS.
```

My working environment:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.1.0 (2021-05-18)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19042)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Chinese (Simplified)_China.936  LC_CTYPE=Chinese (Simplified)_China.936   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Chinese (Simplified)_China.936 LC_NUMERIC=C                              
[5] LC_TIME=Chinese (Simplified)_China.936    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] devtools_2.4.2 usethis_2.0.1 

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] rstudioapi_0.13   magrittr_2.0.1    pkgload_1.2.1     R6_2.5.0         
 [5] rlang_0.4.11      fastmap_1.1.0     tools_4.1.0       pkgbuild_1.2.0   
 [9] sessioninfo_1.1.1 cli_3.0.0         withr_2.4.2       ellipsis_0.3.2   
[13] remotes_2.4.0     rprojroot_2.0.2   lifecycle_1.0.0   crayon_1.4.1     
[17] processx_3.5.2    purrr_0.3.4       callr_3.7.0       fs_1.5.0         
[21] ps_1.6.0          curl_4.3.1        testthat_3.0.4    memoise_2.0.0    
[25] glue_1.4.2        cachem_1.0.5      compiler_4.1.0    desc_1.3.0       
[29] prettyunits_1.1.1
```

The below include the warning information when I `install and restart` the package.

```
In file included from C:/Users/wenjianb/Documents/R/win-library/4.1/Rcpp/include/RcppCommon.h:118,
                    from C:/Users/wenjianb/Documents/R/win-library/4.1/RcppArmadillo/include/RcppArmadilloForward.h:26,
                    from C:/Users/wenjianb/Documents/R/win-library/4.1/RcppArmadillo/include/RcppArmadillo.h:31,
                    from RcppExports.cpp:4:
   C:/Users/wenjianb/Documents/R/win-library/4.1/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/routines.h: In function 'const char* Rcpp::type2name(SEXP)':
   C:/Users/wenjianb/Documents/R/win-library/4.1/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/routines.h:70:73: warning: cast between incompatible function types from 'DL_FUNC' {aka 'void* (*)()'} to 'Fun' {aka 'const char* (*)(SEXPREC*)'} [-Wcast-function-type]
        #define GET_CALLABLE(__FUN__) (Fun) R_GetCCallable( "Rcpp", __FUN__ )
                                                                            ^
   C:/Users/wenjianb/Documents/R/win-library/4.1/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/routines.h:74:26: note: in expansion of macro 'GET_CALLABLE'
            static Fun fun = GET_CALLABLE("type2name");
                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~
   C:/Users/wenjianb/Documents/R/win-library/4.1/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/routines.h: In function 'long unsigned int Rcpp::internal::enterRNGScope()':
   C:/Users/wenjianb/Documents/R/win-library/4.1/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/routines.h:70:73: warning: cast between incompatible function types from 'DL_FUNC' {aka 'void* (*)()'} to 'Fun' {aka 'long unsigned int (*)()'} [-Wcast-function-type]
        #define GET_CALLABLE(__FUN__) (Fun) R_GetCCallable( "Rcpp", __FUN__ )
                                                                            ^
   C:/Users/wenjianb/Documents/R/win-library/4.1/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/routines.h:81:30: note: in expansion of macro 'GET_CALLABLE'
                static Fun fun = GET_CALLABLE("enterRNGScope");
                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~
   C:/Users/wenjianb/Documents/R/win-library/4.1/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/routines.h: In function 'long unsigned int Rcpp::internal::exitRNGScope()':
   C:/Users/wenjianb/Documents/R/win-library/4.1/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/routines.h:70:73: warning: cast between incompatible function types from 'DL_FUNC' {aka 'void* (*)()'} to 'Fun' {aka 'long unsigned int (*)()'} [-Wcast-function-type]
        #define GET_CALLABLE(__FUN__) (Fun) R_GetCCallable( "Rcpp", __FUN__ )
                                                                            ^
   C:/Users/wenjianb/Documents/R/win-library/4.1/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/routines.h:87:30: note: in expansion of macro 'GET_CALLABLE'
                static Fun fun = GET_CALLABLE("exitRNGScope");
                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~
   C:/Users/wenjianb/Documents/R/win-library/4.1/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/routines.h: In function 'long unsigned int Rcpp::internal::beginSuspendRNGSynchronization()':
   C:/Users/wenjianb/Documents/R/win-library/4.1/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/routines.h:70:73: warning: cast between incompatible function types from 'DL_FUNC' {aka 'void* (*)()'} to 'Fun' {aka 'long unsigned int (*)()'} [-Wcast-function-type]
        #define GET_CALLABLE(__FUN__) (Fun) R_GetCCallable( "Rcpp", __FUN__ )
                                                                            ^
```

The other warnings are all similar to the above.

Thank you all in advance.
Wenjian

Comment: What is the command you ran, i.e. which package were you trying to install?  (And both Rcpp and RcppArmadillo are now at newer versions 1.0.7 and 0.10.6.0.0, respectively.)

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Thank you for the response. I have added more details in the question. `library(devtools); install_github("GeneticAnalysisinBiobanks/GRAB", INSTALL_opts=c("--no-multiarch"))` can show the warning information. The below is the [link](https://github.com/GeneticAnalysisinBiobanks/GRAB)

Comment: It installs just fine for me (modulo a lot of compiler warnings) using Rcpp 1.0.7 and RcppArmadillo 0.10.6.0.0 so I suggest you update those two libraries.  If your issue was just about the warnings, you will have to study (and fix) the code. I have a number of packages exporting C level functions too that do not exhibit it so you must have something causing it -- sometimes just a bad `#define` or different header order.  That said, warnings are just that: not errors.  A nuisance and a hint you should change something but it still works.